# Percentage to change div width in JS

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a very basic script that calculates and changes the width of a div but its not working it keeps giving a 100 % result .

My script is like this:

```
<script>
var hp = <? echo $row['hp']; ?>;
var max = <? echo $row['maxhp']; ?>;
var perc = Math.round(hp/max * 100);
if(perc > 100) perc = 100;
else if(perc < 0 ) perc = 0;
d = document.getElementById('health');
d.style.width= perc+"%";
</script>

<div id="health" style="background-color:green;min-height:5px;"></div>
```

The PHP numbers are showing correct in the JS as:

```
var hp = 500;
var max = 2500;
```

Any ideas why it might not be working ?

Comment: Thats created on line 4? What is wrong with it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait until the document (DOM) to load first.

```
//head

$(function(){      //same as "onload" (jQuery)
    var hp = 500,
        max = 2500,
        perc = Math.round(hp/max * 100);
    if(perc > 100){
        perc = 100;
    }else if(perc < 0 ){
        perc = 0; 
    }
      //have to wait until DOM loaded, or else it return "not found"
    d = document.getElementById('health');
    d.style.width= perc+"%";
    alert(perc+"%");   
});​
```

DEMO: [***`http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/uUBVd/`***](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/uUBVd/)

[image]

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/i0Xcr.jpg this is the equivalent without jquery right ? Or am i missing something in mine compared to yours?

Comment: @Dave, no, `window.onload` is not equivalent to `$()`. What I used is `load when DOM has loaded`. [jQuery document](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Is there a non library equivalent to $ in jquery?

Comment: You can use `<body onload="yourFunction()">`, but it'll be ugly. :(

Comment: It'll do :P no put using a library for something this small :P Thanks!

Comment: Maybe there are errors in your other code. (no problem: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/6ysXd/)

Comment: @Dave do the jsFiddle links that Derek has provided work for you? Can you show us your other code, because there are several answers here that work perfectly fine for us.

Comment: I can't see a problem either but the bar still comes out at 100% even though perc is showing to be not 100. I tested this by doing this: http://www.paste.to/MzYyMjY5 as you can guess no red shows. Because the green div is 100% the width

Comment: @Dave, how about this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/P95YW/ Do you see any error in this one?

Comment: No it shows correctly on that - but it uses jquery im trying to not use a library =/

Comment: It wasn't but i altered it to be non jquery...which he explained in the comments ^

Comment: @Dave, I don't see where is the problem. Can you reproduce a demo in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1):

#### Its working, see a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/bmvBB/)

So, the problem is the script is running before the element is loaded on the DOM. Put the script after the HTML

```
<div id="health" style="background-color:green;min-height:5px;"></div>
<script>
var hp = <? echo $row['hp']; ?>;
var max = <? echo $row['maxhp']; ?>;
var perc = Math.round(hp/max * 100);
if(perc > 100) perc = 100;
else if(perc < 0 ) perc = 0;
d = document.getElementById('health');
d.style.width= perc+"%";
</script>
```

Comment: But i put all JS in the head of HTML isn't that where JS is meant to be placed?

Comment: @Dave, Yes it is, but you have to wait until the document to load first. `window.onload = (function(){ blah blah blah })` [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/uUBVd/)

Comment: One step ahead just tried that :P http://www.paste.to/MzYyMjUz this is the page source, showing the numbers from the PHP. Still gives me 100% width green div.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing your JavaScript before the element has loaded.  Position your script block after the div in your html.

**Edit:**

Or, place your code in an onload handler.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var hp = <? echo $row['hp']; ?>; 
    var max = <? echo $row['maxhp']; ?>; 
    var perc = Math.round(hp/max * 100); 
    if(perc > 100) perc = 100; 
    else if(perc < 0 ) perc = 0; 
    d = document.getElementById('health'); 
    d.style.width= perc+"%"; 
}
```

Or, don't use JavaScript at all. Just emit the value directly into the div's style attribute.

**Edit:** Also, don't use `document.write()` after the page has been loaded.  If you comment out your call to `document.write()`, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/2KLQq/

Notice that if you uncomment the `document.write()` in my jsfiddle and run it, it no longer works.

Comment: I thought JS has to be in the head of the HTML page so how does that work ?

Comment: Maybe I took your code too literally, because you don't appear to have your script in the head above.  But anyway, no, the script does not need to be in the head.

Comment: Is there a way i can make it a function and call it from the page ?

Comment: How would i put the value directly in if its calculated in JS?

Comment: @dave - It's just arithmetic, do the calculation in PHP.

Comment: I'm trying to do it JS to lower server maths as much as possible :)

Comment: @dave - do it wherever you prefer, but don't fool yourself into believing that doing this kind of math on the server costs you even 1 millisecond.  It is probably more taxing to the server to write an extra value to the page than to do some simple math. I'd be more concerned about the UI shifting when the JavaScript is executed.

Comment: whlst its not big maths - im trying to do as much maths in JS over server as it adds up with more n more users.

Comment: @dave - it turns out the real problem is `document.write ()`.  You didn't mention that in your question, but I saw it in your "paste.to".  See my updated answer.

Comment: i added that afterwards to check perc was not 100 in value.. =/ but i removed it and its still not working. Its so confusing. Im wondering if its cos the script is called via ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be because your `<script>` gets executed before `<div>` is rendered, try swapping around those elements and see if it works.

```
<div id="health" style="background-color:green;min-height:5px;"></div>

<script>
var hp = <? echo $row['hp']; ?>;
var max = <? echo $row['maxhp']; ?>;
var perc = Math.round(hp/max * 100);
if(perc > 100) perc = 100;
else if(perc < 0 ) perc = 0;
d = document.getElementById('health');
d.style.width= perc+"%";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem, you need to detect when the DOM is loaded and then run your calculations.

You can use `window.onload` to detect when the window has loaded and run a function. If you are using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) you can use `$(document).ready();` or `$(window).load();`.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
        var hp = 500; //hardcoded, normally outputted via php <?=$row['hp']; ?>
        var max = 2500; //hardcoded, normally output via php <?=$row['maxhp']; ?>
        var perc = Math.round(hp/max * 100);

        if(perc > 100)
        {perc = 100;}

        else if(perc < 0 )
        {perc = 0;}

        d = document.getElementById('health');
        d.style.width= perc+"%";
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="health" style="background-color:green;min-height:5px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeh i have tried this but still get 100% See paste to: http://www.paste.to/MzYyMjU4 this is the page source so you can see the numbers.